# ReleaseStringUTFChars not working for std::string

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, stdstring

I use std::string in my jni function, and I fail to release it using ReleaseStringUTFChars.
The error I get is:

error: no matching function for call to NIEnv::ReleaseStringUTF   env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, dir);

I understand, that instead of string, the function expects to get char, but I don't have such variable. What should I do?

This is my jni function:

```
void Java_com_example_android_OpenCVActivity_test (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jstring path){

    std::string dir = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, 0);
   ....
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, dir);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it exactly the same value you got from `GetStringUTFChars().` You're not. You're passing whatever `std::string` gives you, which isn't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: But how do I get the exact value from GetStringUTFChars()?

Comment: Err, store it into a *variable?* You already had it, as a return value, but all you did with it was to pass it as a constructor parameter to `std::string::string().`

Answer (score 0):

The book [Mastering Android NDK](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/p9dOCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) defines the function

```
auto ConvertJString(JNIEnv* env, jstring str) -> std::string
{
    if (!str) { return std::string(); }
    auto const len = env->GetStringUTFLength(str);
    auto const strChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, static_cast<jboolean*>(0));
    std::string result(strChars, len);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, strChars);
    return result;
}
```

This handles getting and releasing the string as well as returning an `std::string`.