# C++ on android, how to get app's document directory?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm integrating a native c++ library (sqlite3) into android, in order to save the database file I need a path to put it somewhere, on iOS I used this code to get the documents directory:

```cpp
char *home = getenv("HOME");
```

However this environment variable not available on Android, is there anyway to get the applications documents path from the c++ or is it necessary to always get it from some higher java call?

Thanks a lot for the help!

#### Edit

After looking around, I found this small snippet that I already had in my codebase:

```java
SequelModule.initialize(
      this.getReactApplicationContext().getJavaScriptContextHolder().get(),
      this.getReactApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
    );
```

which is being passed to my `cpp-adapter.cpp`, how do I convert the second value (the absolute path) JNI/Java string into a C++ std::string?

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include "react-native-sequel.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_reactnativesequel_SequelModule_initialize(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jlong jsiPtr) {
    installSequel(*reinterpret_cast<facebook::jsi::Runtime*>(jsiPtr));
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_reactnativesequel_SequelModule_destruct(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz) {
  cleanUpSequel();
}
```

Comment: "I'm integrating a native c++ library (sqlite3) into android" -- Android already has SQLite. If, for some reason, you want an external copy of SQLite, see https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android or https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher for pre-built ones. "is it necessary to always get it from some higher java call?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: Not interested in java implementations or android only implementations, it is also a process for me to learn c++/sqlite, so I will continue with my own implementation thanks

Thanks a lot for the info regarding the java call though, it confirms my own findings

Comment: You've shown Java code where you call a native function with two arguments, but the corresponding C++ function only takes one. That doesn't add up. In any case, once you have the `jstring`, creating a `std::string` is pretty straight-forward. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62600580/1524450

Comment: Yeah, I didn't update the c++ function call because it wasn't being used before, but your answer is exactly what I needed, thanks!